# how do i create a list enviroment with text flushed on the right

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I want to create a list environment, where the text that describes each item on the list is to the right and centered, forming a kind of box so to speak. Here is the code of want i mean by it

```
      \begin{verbatim}
       -item 1: a very interesting text, with
                lots of words, all on the right
                inside this box
       
       -item 2: another very insteresting text,
                with lots of complicated words,
                all align on the right
       
       -item 3: a very interesting text, with
                lots of words, all on the right
                inside this box
       
       -item 4: another very insteresting text,
                with lots of complicated words,
                all align on the right
       \end{verbatim}
```

and here is an image of the text [image]

Please try to use the simplest code you can think of. I'm not very good at LaTex. If this is only possible with some package, please explain to me how I adjust the width of the items and the space that the text on each item can occupy, thank you.

Comment: See also: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures#Customizing_lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={-item \arabic*:},left=0cm]\raggedright
\item a very interesting text, with
lots of words, all on the right
inside this box

\item another very insteresting text,
with lots of complicated words,
all align on the right

\item  a very interesting text, with
lots of words, all on the right
inside this box

\item  another very insteresting text,
with lots of complicated words,
all align on the right
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```