How to align long labels to the left, and to remove the indent of the text
I want to create a list environment, with long labels that are align to the left , and  where the text that describes each item on the list is to the right and centered, forming a kind of box so to speak. Here is the code of want i mean by it
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} %pacote de cor
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}[
                   leftmargin=* %left text margin align with label right margin
                   widest=Evidências de Auditoria :
                   ]
\item [Auditoria : ] Processo sistemático, independente e documentado para 
            obter evidências de auditoria e avaliá-las objetivamente 
            para determinar a extensão em que os critérios de auditoria 
            são atendidos.

\item [Critérios de Auditoria : ] Conjunto de políticas, procedimentos ou requisitos usados 
                         como referência. Pode incluir documentos como normas de
                         sistemas de gestão, legislação, regulamentos, contratos 
                         ou códigos de prática.

\item [Evidências de Auditoria :] Registros, declarações de fatos ou outras informações
                          relevantes e verificáveis, coletadas durante a auditoria.
\end{description}
\end{document}


Please provide a minimal example showing what you've tried. Are you using enumitem? You've applied the tag ....

The answer to your previous question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/700167/) should give you a good starting point. What's the problem adjusting it exactly? Have you looked at enumitem's manual? It is pretty well documented.

i tried using enumitem. In the manual it has a code that does almoust what i want, but the align of the labels are to the left.  The code is
\begin{enumerate}[left=0pt .. \parindent].
As for my previous question, the The answer was to use another package to try to generate this. But even though it was also close to what I wanted, it wasn't exactly what I wanted.

A list typically uses the same \leftmargin for every \item, such as the description environment.  At best you could use a bunch of \trivlists, or combine a constant \leftmargin with \hangindent.

Note that \leftmargin is also used to increment \@totalleftmargin for nested lists.

i just learned within the enumitem package, using the comand "leftmargin=*" and "widest=longest label text" you align the left margin of the item text to the right margin of the longest label text. I still make align the leftmargin of the item text to the rightmargin of the labelwidth.

Found the solution on anothers post enter link description here. The question was

Change hanging indent in description list

The one that did the code was

Philippe Goutet

\usepackage{calc}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\DESCRIPTION@original@item}{}
\let\DESCRIPTION@original@item\item
\newcommand*{\DESCRIPTION@envir}{DESCRIPTION}
\newlength{\DESCRIPTION@totalleftmargin}
\newlength{\DESCRIPTION@linewidth}
\newcommand{\DESCRIPTION@makelabel}[1]{\llap{#1}}%
\newcommand{\DESCRIPTION@item}[1][]{%
\setlength{\@totalleftmargin}%
   {\DESCRIPTION@totalleftmargin+\widthof{\textbf{#1 }}-\leftmargin}%
\setlength{\linewidth}
   {\DESCRIPTION@linewidth-\widthof{\textbf{#1 }}+\leftmargin}%
\par\parshape \@ne \@totalleftmargin \linewidth
\DESCRIPTION@original@item[\textbf{#1}]%
 }
\newenvironment{DESCRIPTION}
{\list{}{\setlength{\labelwidth}{0cm}%
       \let\makelabel\DESCRIPTION@makelabel}%
\setlength{\DESCRIPTION@totalleftmargin}{\@totalleftmargin}%
\setlength{\DESCRIPTION@linewidth}{\linewidth}%
\renewcommand{\item}{\ifx\@currenvir\DESCRIPTION@envir
                       \expandafter\DESCRIPTION@item
                    \else
                       \expandafter\DESCRIPTION@original@item
                    \fi}}
 {\endlist}
\makeatother
 \begin{document}
 \begin{DESCRIPTION}
 \item[Label the first] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
                        elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
                        dolore magna aliqua.
\item[The longest label] Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
                         ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                         consequat.
\item[Shrtlbl] Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
               cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
\end{DESCRIPTION}

\end{document}

